# Put a timestamp in a wordpress post

Tags: wordpress

I want to generate a timestamp on the fly and put it INTO every wordpress post.

Obviously I can not put javascript directly into a workpress post.
What's the simplest and most light way of doing it?

Comment: I will need to only display it in one post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every wordpress post already has a timestamp to go with it. You just have to get it out of the database with [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date) and display it.

When you're in the wordpress loop you would call it like so (excerpt from the link provided):

```
<?php the_date('Y-m-d', '<span>', '</span>'); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you! Could I use "edit" in admin panel to add this timestamp to a post? suppose I want to publish exactly like this. "We have some big news today (10:00 7/8/2014<- the timestamp). There is a celebration in the union square and a firework was stated and blew...'    And I should edit "We have some big news today (<?php the_date('Y-m-d', '<span>', '</span>'); ?><- the timestamp). There is a celebration in the union square and a firework was stated and blew..." Will the PhP code display well in wordpress?

Comment: I mean't for the php code to be put into the theme which means editing the source code of the theme you're using. If you want to drop the date right into the post through the text box you can try using this plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/extra-shortcodes/ . You will have to read up on what shortcodes are and how to use them.  This may help http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/01/wordpress-shortcodes-complete-guide/ . If you havn't installed a plugin before ge here http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/step-by-step-guide-to-install-a-wordpress-plugin-for-beginners/ . Hope that helps